Looking for the right term for a second generation member of a club or organization
I'm tasked with introducing a speaker who is the daughter of an early member of an organization. Do I say she is a legacy member? Or is there a better term?
Searching here, the thesaurus, dictionary and internet has not offered any on topic results.

What don't you like about "second generation member"?

I didn't know the specific usage before, but apparently A legacy is someone who has a special relationship to a sorority because of a biological relationship to someone who is already a member, such as a mother or sister. But even within the narrow context of sorority membership, that link points out that legacies are defined differently by each of the 26 National Panhellenic Conference member organizations. I wouldn't use it for the context here, even now I recognize that "relative" aspect.

"Second-generation" member sounds nice and respectful to me, and would clearly identify the person as a direct offspring of a founder or early member.

Legacy could be the right term, but one has to carefully consider one's audience. First, this sense of the term is unlikely to be recognised outside the US.  Second, the OP obviously intends the term as a commendation, and it may be so perceived by some, but not by those who are used to seeing it (a) in the criticisms of giving priority in admission to educational institutions on the basis of the candidate's legacy status, or (b) in software-related contexts (where its stands for something we can't wait to get rid of).

Guys, wherever you found it, how could you yourselves ever justify 'a legacy'?

Is the actually a member? She can't be a legacy member if she's not a member in the first place. "legacy" usually means that being a relative helped her become a member. For example, many colleges automatically accept  applications from legacies.

Thank you all for your answers.
Barmar - yes, she is a member of the same organization as her mother.
The audience is US based so I considered “second generation member”, but most of the references I found defined it as a second generation immigrant.
Maybe I’ll just say she has followed her mother’s passion for the organizations interests.

first descendant member
